# Como fazer uma variável definir quantas vezes vou ter que repetir uma entrada? C

Tags: c

A primeira linha de entrada contém um valor inteiro N que indica os vários casos de teste que vem a seguir. Cada caso de teste contém um inteiro Quantia (1 ≤ Quantia ≤ 15) que representa a quantidade de cobaias utilizadas e um caractere Tipo ('C', 'R' ou 'S'), indicando o tipo de cobaia (R:Rato S:Sapo C:Coelho).... 
Como fazer esse valor inteiro N definir o número de entradas (experimentos) que vou ter que entrar?

Comment: Já tentou um laço `for`?

Comment: Não, e não sei bem como faria, sou novo em programação, tem como exemplificar a formatação nesse caso específico?

Comment: Para entender melhor o funcionamento do StackOverflow em português leia: [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).